# Joomla + K2 + SIGpro giving strange error

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I've just installed my Joomla 2.5.4, K2 2.5.6 and SIG pro 2.5.3 and everything looks fine except that when I upload a zip file containing a few images to use as Image Gallery, I get this error in K2 item editing interface:

**The was a problem converting the source image.
There was a problem rendering your image gallery. Please make sure that the folder you are using in the Simple Image Gallery PRO plugin tags exists and contains valid image files. The plugin could not locate the folder: media/k2/galleries/27**

The funny part is that I can see my images uploaded in "media/k2/galleries/27" but in both administrator interface and front-end item view, I have "{gallery}27{/gallery}".

I've searched everywhere and people facing this problem were giving wrong access to media folder or zipping a folder containing image (not the images).

I have made these settings but problem still exists:

- Access to media folder and all folders inside it are 777
- Access to all other folders is 775
- I'm sure about the zip file I'm uploading. It only contains JPEG
  images, all of them are less than 80K

I have Ubuntu server and I'm using NginX web-server, but I get the same error in Apache.

***PS:** And of course I know here is not a good place to ask questions about these tools, but I'm in a bad situation and I need help!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a web-server and FTP created files access problem.

I described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10978268/893111

Answer (score 0):

Activate Simple Image Gallery PRO plugin from backend.

Comment: It's already activated. If it wasn't I couldn't even get any errors!

Answer (score -1):

There was a problem rendering your image gallery, please make sure that the folder you are using in the **Simple Image Gallery Pro** plugin tags exists and contains valid image files.
The plugin could not locate the folder